# ‘The’ Days of Our Lives

Tags: definite-articles

In the show 'Friends' there is an exchange between Ross and Joey that goes like this:

> *Joey:* I'm in this show called 'The Days of Our Lives'.
>   *Ross:* Dude, it's just 'Days of Our Lives'. There's no 'the'.

Sadly, I fail to see humor in this and it's most likely due to my poor understanding of the many meanings of the article 'the'.

I also think understanding this joke could make me understand how the reception of the name "The Facebook" differs from just "Facebook" (the site used to be called thefacebook.com in the past, there's even a mention of that in the movie "The Social Network").

Could you help me understand this, please?

Comment: _Days of Our Lives_ is the title of a show. The show could have been called _The Days of Our Lives_ with no significant change in meaning, but it isn’t. Joey simply says the name of his own (as it were) TV show incorrectly, and Ross corrects him. Also, ‘the’ is an article (it is the definite article), not a preposition.

Comment: The movie, I recall, shows how it was one of the founders of Napster who suggested dropping _the_. 'The Facebook' was originally a specific site centred on Harvard. Dropping the article makes it generic.

Comment: Thank you all for the clarification. Even more so, now that I know the question has little to do with the English language itself (and Janus Bahs Jacquet, thanks for fixing my question, too).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with the meanings of *the*. The joke is just that the actor who is actually in the show doesn't even know the show's name.

About the one point of relevance to English, is that it's common for titles to start with the indefinite article, but not universal, meaning that it would be a reasonable mistake for many people to make, but not if they were actually acting in the show.