# The definite article 'the' before the names of TV shows

Tags: definite-articles, connotation

Rewatching 'The one in Barbados' episode of 'Friends' TV series, I stumbled upon a joke that seemed to sail over my head the first time I heard it.

> **Joey:** No, God, no! No! No no, I'm an actor. You'd probably recognize me from a little show called "The Days of Our Lives"
>
> **Ross:** Dude, it's just "Days of Our Lives"... there's no the.

Could anyone please clarify if Joey deliberatly attached the definite article 'the' to the TV show name to give a ring to it, as if he was more than sure the name of the show alone would impress the listener, or he merely made a technical mistake, not implying anything of the above?

Here is the follow-up question: could appending the definite article 'the' to the name possibly attach importance of any sort or solidity for that matter to it?

Comment: Remarkably, we have a past question on this same episode, *['The' Days of Our Life](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142936/)*

Comment: Thank you very much.
Could you please tell me if there is even a slim chance that Joey added 'the' to highlight the name of the show, as if to give a special flavor to it? Can the article 'the' possibly attach any sort of solidity to a subject, when placed before it?

Comment: A former UK Prime Minister was ridiculed for trying to be matey, by talking about "watching The Eastenders" which he plainly did not do. It was like saying "I watch The Friends".

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Weather Vane.
Does it mean Joey meant none of what I surmised (overthought, rather), and he simply made a mistake in the TV show name the same way the former Prime Minister did?

Comment: Over 60 years afo in the US, NBC debuted  2 TV shows, TODAY, and TONIGHT!. They survive, however they are almost always called The Today Show, and The Tonight Show by viewers . The additional words clarify intent when  viewer say they are going to watch.

Comment: The show is scripted - but sometimes shows contain an ad-lib when recorded which the editor leaves in - who knows? Re comment from @J.Taylor it is quite reasonable to be more specific with those shows. If I say "I will be watching Tonight" that might be less clear than "I will be watching Friends".

Comment: There are various reasons for correctly omitting articles (look up 'null article' for some). Here, I'd say that 'how it sounds' was the main factor informing the choice, though I'm not enamoured with either of them. Enamoured of, if you prefer.